# Universal Windows App: Windows App Certification Kit - Test Results - Failed

Tags: windows, ionic2

I have developed an Universal Windows App with ionic framework using sql lite3. The build is successful when compiled, but when I create an package(.appx), the package created without fail, but when I launch the certification test I am getting issues in the Windows App Certification Kit results.

Below are the test results which got failed.

1. Windows security features test

FAILED
Binary analyzer
Error Found: The binary analyzer test detected the following errors:
File C:\Program Files\windowsapps\SQLite3.UWP.dll has failed the WXCheck check.
Impact if not fixed: If the app doesn’t use the available Windows protections, it can increase the vulnerability of the customer's computer to malware.
How to fix: Apply the required linker options - SAFESEH, DYNAMICBASE, NXCOMPAT, and APPCONTAINER - when you link the app. See links below for more information:

2. Supported API test

FAILED
Supported APIs
Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
API _CrtDbgReport in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _CrtDbgReportW in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API **stdio_common_vsprintf_s in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _cexit in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _configure_narrow_argv in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _crt_at_quick_exit in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _crt_atexit in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _execute_onexit_table in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _free_dbg in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _initialize_narrow_environment in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _initialize_onexit_table in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _initterm in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _initterm_e in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _localtime64_s in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _msize in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _register_onexit_function in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _seh_filter_dll in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _wmakepath_s in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _wsplitpath_s in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API free in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API malloc in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API qsort in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API rand_s in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API realloc in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API strcat_s in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API strcmp in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API strcpy_s in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API strlen in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API strncmp in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API wcscmp in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API wcscpy_s in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API wcslen in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ??0COMException@Platform@@QE$AAA@H@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ??0NotImplementedException@Platform@@QE$AAA@XZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ??0Object@Platform@@QE$AAA@XZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?AlignedFree@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAXPEAX@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?Allocate@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAPEAX_K0@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?AllocateException@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAPEAX_K0@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?Free@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAXPEAX@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?GetActivationFactory@Details@Platform@@YAJPEAVModuleBase@1WRL@Microsoft@@PEAUHSTRING**@@PEAPEAUIActivationFactory@@@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?GetIidsFn@@YAJHPEAKPEBU__s_GUID@@PEAPEAVGuid@Platform@@@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?InitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAJH@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?ReleaseTarget@ControlBlock@Details@Platform@@AEAAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?TerminateModule@Details@Platform@@YA_NPEAVModuleBase@1WRL@Microsoft@@@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?UninitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAXH@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseAccessDeniedException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseCOMException@@YAXJ@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseChangedStateException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseClassNotRegisteredException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseDisconnectedException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseFailureException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseInvalidArgumentException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseInvalidCastException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseNotImplementedException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseNullReferenceException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseObjectDisposedException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOperationCanceledException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOutOfBoundsException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOutOfMemoryException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseWrongThreadException@@YAXXZ in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API ?__abi_translateCurrentException@@YAJ_N@Z in vccorlib140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API _CxxThrowException in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API __C_specific_handler in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API __CxxFrameHandler3 in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API __std_type_info_destroy_list in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API __vcrt_GetModuleFileNameW in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API __vcrt_GetModuleHandleW in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API __vcrt_LoadLibraryExW in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API memcmp in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API memcpy in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API memmove in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
API memset in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLite3.UWP.dll calls this API.
Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps violates the Windows Store certification requirements. 
How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps. Please note, apps that are built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled (where applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and with .NET Native enabled if applicable. See the link below for more information: 
Alternatives to Windows APIs in Windows Store apps.

3. Debug configuration test

FAILED
Debug configuration
Error Found: The debug configuration test detected the following errors:
The binary SQLite3.UWP.dll is built in debug mode.
Impact if not fixed: Windows Store doesn’t allow a debug version of an app. 
How to fix: Please make sure the app isn’t linking to any debug versions of a framework and it is built with release configuration with optimization enabled. If this is a managed app please make sure you have installed the correct version of .NET framework.

Note: All the projects are configured in released mode.

Please suggest a solution for this. I am using Visual Studio Community 2017.

Thanks,
Maruthi